# Check if List of Structs Contains an element

Tags: c#, list, struct, contains

I've got struct Client and List of Clients.

```
struct Client
        {
            public IPEndPoint endpoint;   
            public string ClientName;
        }
List<Client> clientList = new List<Client>();
```

How can I check if my list contains Client with specific name? I've tried to do it like that

```
if(clientList.Find(Client => Client.ClientName == userNickname)
```

But it doesn't return bool value unfortunately.

Comment: What does _"it doesn't return bool value"_ mean? Does this give you a compiler error, or a runtime exception? What did your research for that error text give you? Or, in other words: what does `Find()` return and what does `if()` want? What exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: Just a second of googling brings us to a ton of duplicates...

Comment: I wanted to check if Client with specific name exists in my list. The Find() operator returns whole Client object and my compiler won't let me use it inside if statement. 
I was googling that, I swear. I've tried multiple solutions but somehow I must've overlook an Any() operator

Comment: If you want to use `Find` you can simply check if the result of `Find` is `null`: `if(clientList.Find(...) != null)`

Comment: I asked you that question to let you think it out for yourself, not as to evoke an actual answer to that question. :) If `Find()` returns one `Client` when found and something else, namely `null` when not, what should your `if()` contain?

Comment: Oh, that's right. Now I feel dumb. Thank you all for you help. I must go away now in shame.

Comment: Don't feel dumb, sometimes it just won't click. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use LINQ's  [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) method:

```
bool contains = clientList.Any(client => client.ClientName == userNickname);
```

---

`Any` is easier in this case than `Find()` because `Find()` returns an instance of `Client`. You would need a further comparison (either to `default(Client)` like Jodrell suggested or again compare the names).

Comment: I can't use Contains since an error occurs "cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Program.Client' because it is not a delegate type". But 'Any' works perfect :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

erm,

```
if (clientList.Find(Client => Client.ClientName == userNickname).ClientName != userNickname)
...
```

if you read the documentation for [`List<T>.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll see that if no element of the list returns true for the `predicate` the default value of `T` will be returned.

Obviously, this won't work if you want to search for a `Client` with a `null` name.

The usage is rather clumsy and doesn't work very well  with structures. Consider making `Client` a class or overriding equality for `Client` or making `Client` immutable or just doing something else.